# How to install kate5

Tags: kate

I tried to install the latest version of kde editor kate, but nothing changed.
I took the source code: git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kate;
I followed http://kate-editor.org/get-it/'s instructions;
Now, when I run ~/kde/usr/bin/kate-v is the same version that was:

```
$ ~/kde/usr/bin/kate -v
Qt: 4.8.6
Plataforma de desenvolvimento KDE: 4.14.1
Kate: 3.14.1
```

How I do to install the lastest version?

Grateful

Comment: Could you please accept the answer or comment on whether the answers solve your problem? - StackOverflow works this way - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the version in the About dialog is built from the KDE version, so it does not all reflect whether you are running a self-compiled one or not. Second, you should run Kate with all environment variables properly set - just running the executable will probably load the wrong ktexteditor.so library.

The easiest way to get Kate5 is to install a distribution that ships Kate5 (probably along with Plasma 5).

If you already have a KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5) environment available, then you can also build Kate5 from sources by following the [build instructions](http://kate-editor.org/get-it/). These were updated in June 2015.

If you are still on KDE 4.x and you have no KDE Frameworks 5 packages installed, then you also need to build KDE Frameworks 5 from sources. In this case, you have to follow the [KF5 build instructions](https://community.kde.org/Frameworks/Building). If you've questions, feel free to ask on [kde-frameworks-devel@kde.org](https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/kde-frameworks-devel) and/or on the [Kate mailing list](https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/kwrite-devel).